# Variable Column Names

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am selecting data from two tables using a join. Table A holds current table b last snapshot data. Simple example....

```
TableA
ProductID uniqueidentifier
ProductName VarChar(200)
Qty INT
Date DateTime

TableB
ProductID uniqueidentifier
ProductName VarChar(200)
Qty INT
DateTaken DateTime

SELECT a.ProductName, a.Qty, b.Qty From TableA a join TableB b on a.ProductID = 
b.ProductID
```

Is there a way I can Alias the column name using data from the row...

```
SELECT a.ProductName, a.Qty As ['Quantity ' + a.DateTaken], b.Qty As ['Quantity ' + b.DateTaken] From TableA a join TableB b on a.ProductID = 
b.ProductID
```

Without using dynamic SQL

Comment: No. For this (rather strange requirement), you will _have_ to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Not that I know of. What would you expect if the statement returns two records with each a different date? How is SQL Server to know?

Comment: The two table hold snapshots of data taken at a specific date.  I want the column name to be "Qty As At {Date}" (long story it would just make life easier!). The Select will only ever return one row for each item.

Comment: @Fred - I *assumed* that much but again, how is SQL Server to know :)

Comment: It may make things easier down the line (can't say I understand how that will be). But consider that you can return the `DateTaken` as part of the result set.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I may be missing something! What would SQL Server need to know? I have one row of data with 2 Qty and 2 dates I just want the dates to be in the alias of the corresponding Qtys. Easy enough with dynamic SQL just wondered if it was possible without.

Comment: @Fred - I wasn't trying to be pedantic *(it comes naturally)* but SQL Server can't know upfront that that statement is going to return only one row and even if it could, I don't know any way besides dynamic SQL on how to do it.

Comment: @Oded I have a bespoke reporting tool (bad) that I have no control over and cannot change. It uses the column names as the column headers in the report. Hence it would be easier.

Comment: As @Lieven and I said, dynamic SQL is the only way.

Comment: @Oded I kind of expected that but thought it worth an ask! Thaks anyway guys

Comment: How are you consuming this?  Could you do a top 1 for names union values and then get the names from the first row?

Comment: @Blam All I can do is set the datasource of the report in the form of a SQL statement or a stored procedure. I can also pass variables to both.  I have now written the dynamic sql statement in a SP and its working fine. I understand why the column name cannot be data from a row, however I still think it would be cool to be able to set the name of a column using a variable `Col1 as @Col1Name`